# Adding a second array into the foreach query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I've got 2 dynamic inputs, where the amount of subsequent fields change from form to form, so I use an array to capture the field inputs.

Currently the script inserts an autoincremented ID taken from a previous query, and also inserts the product_id for each arrays element, into a column.

So If I have two inputs from product_ids[] (123 & 456) they would go into the table like this:

ID|product_id

01|123

01|456

I am trying to also get the product_amount in the same table and columns:

ID|product_id|product_amount

01|123|1

01|456|2

```
<input type="text" name="product_ids[]">
<input type="text" name="product_amounts[]">
```

Currently this is working fine for one of the two input's I have like this. Although I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add the product_amounts[] fields as well.

```
$product_ids = array();

foreach($product_id as $p_id)
$product_ids[] = "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '". $p_id ."')";
$product_ids = implode(", ", $product_ids);

$query = "INSERT INTO order_list (ID,product_id) VALUES $product_ids";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I tried an AND operator in the foreach query, but quickly learned it does not work like that.

### EDIT

```
$product_ids = implode(", ", $product_ids, $product_amounts);
$query = "INSERT INTO order_list (ID,product_id,product_amount) VALUES $product_ids";
```

Comment: Your question is bit unclear? try to point out where you want product_amounts array in down code written by you?

Comment: `$product_ids = implode(", ", $product_ids, $product_amounts);`
`$query = "INSERT INTO order_list (ID,product_id,order_amount) VALUES $product_ids";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )

[Source](http://php.net/implode). You are passing three parameters to `implode`, which is invalid. You need to pass the glue, which is the comma and an array. However, even if you fix this, your code will still be illogical (there should be no product amounts in an array called `product_ids`) and unsafe due to a lack of prevention of [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Unfortunately your code is also reluctant to types. If you are using only numbers, then it will run this way, but you should consider using prepared statements.

I would allocate some time to watch some tutorials on youtube. In 1-2 hours you will have enough knowledge to solve your problem.